# IntentService and Binding Pattern

Tags: android

I have IntentService that should use reference from another service via binding:

```
public class BaseIntentService extends IntentService implements ServiceConnection {

    protected NetworkApi network;

    public BaseIntentService() {
        super("BaseIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        network = ((NetworkApiBinder) service).getApi();
        // never be invoked
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        bindService(new Intent(this, NetworkApi.impl), this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindService(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // network always null!!!
    }
}
```

But when I'm using binding like this onServiceConnected never be invoked. I know that IntentService not designed for the binding pattern, but may be there is a common solution for such tasks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But when I'm using binding like this onServiceConnected never be invoked

That is because your `IntentService` is destroyed before the binding request even begins. An `IntentService` is automatically destroyed when `onHandleIntent()` completes all outstanding commands.

> but may be there is a common solution for such tasks

Don't have two services. Get rid of the `IntentService` and move its logic into the other service.

Comment: CommonsWare sir : Why android prevents `IntentService` to be bind from other components?

Comment: @Kushal: Because an `IntentService` is meant to be short-lived (several seconds to perhaps a minute or so). An `IntentService` is automatically destroyed when `onHandleIntent()` completes all outstanding commands.